# Nuget Package Explorer didnt add a *.dll (not *.Resources.dll) to references

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, nuget-package

This seems to be a simple question but i didnt find a clear answer.

After installing [a package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IsoStorageManager/) with a dll to a sample empty wp7 project, everything seems fine (dependencies are pulled correctly), but a dll itself is not added to project references. And i dont see corresponding settings in the Nuget Package Explorer.

How can i say to nuget to add a lib to references automatically?

Comment: For nuget to add the DLL as a reference, it should be in a "lib" folder inside of the package (.nupkg). And with your package this is not the case, the dll is placed in the root of the nupkg file. How are you building the nuget package, how does your command look like?

Comment: I'm just using Nuget Package Explorer. Trying to move to "lib" folder now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said, the DLL should be placed beneath a "lib" folder inside the package (nupkg).
Aside from that it's also recommended to place it in a folder like "lib\net40" if your project depends on features that are new in .NET 4.0.

For more information, [read the nuget documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package)

Comment: Looking like "Nuget Package Explorer" is kinda evil :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2945255/vincent) mentioned, a DLL should be in a Lib folder.

`Nuget Package Explorer` users should check the package via **Tools/Analyze Package**